# MPMoviePlayerController Doesn't Play when receiving a remote control event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

So I've got a MPMoviePlayerController playing a video in the background.

If I tell it to load a different video using remote control notifications it works just fine.
However if I tell it to play the video it doesn't play?

Has anyone else had this problem or found a solution?

Code snippet:

```
   override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent!) {
    if  (event.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl){
        if (event.subtype.toRaw() == 100 || event.subtype.toRaw() == 101){
            didPressPausePlay(self)
        }else if(event.subtype.toRaw() == 104){
            didPressNext(self)
        }else if(event.subtype.toRaw() == 105){
            didPressPrevious(self)
        }
    }
}

 @IBAction func didPressPrevious(sender: AnyObject) {
    videoTitle.text = ""
    if (currentIndex != 0){
        currentIndex--
        currentVideo = parsedVideoIds[currentIndex] as NSString
        videoPlayerViewController = XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController(videoIdentifier: currentVideo);
        videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.backgroundPlaybackEnabled = true;
        videoPlayerViewController.presentInView(self.view);
        videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(customControls);
        videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.play()
        currentImage = 0
        pauseplayButton.setImage(pauseImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

I left out the rest because it all does the same thing.

Comment: Hi, I saw you're using XCDYouTubeKit for Swift, I'm currently using it also and I'm having trouble playing the next youtube video in my playlist. Could you assist me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666063/how-to-play-the-next-youtube-video-in-a-playlist-using-xcdyoutubekit-for-swift ? Thanks