# How to play the next youtube video in a playlist using XCDYouTubeKit for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using XCDYouTubeKit, written as a subclass of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

I'm having an issue playing the next video in my playlist. When I tap the forward button, the state of the player is stopped, and I'm not sure how to resume it?

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    youtubeVideoPlayer = XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController(videoIdentifier: videoID)

    self.view.addSubview( (youtubeVideoPlayer?.view)! )

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "moviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChange:",
        name: MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification,
        object: youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:",
        name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification,
        object: youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "moviePlayerPlaybackDidChange:",
        name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification,
        object: youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "moviePlayerPlayBackDidFinish:",
        name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
        object: youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer)
}

func moviePlayerPlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("moviePlayerPlayBackDidFinish")
    youtubeVideoPlayer!.view.removeFromSuperview()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}

func moviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("moviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChange")
}

func moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange")
    youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer.play()

    let state: MPMoviePlaybackState = (youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer.playbackState)!

    switch state
    {
    case MPMoviePlaybackState.Stopped:
        print("stopped")
        break

    case MPMoviePlaybackState.Interrupted:
        print("interrupted")
        break

    case MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingForward:
        print("forward")
        break

    case MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingBackward:
        print("backward")
        break

    case MPMoviePlaybackState.Paused:
        print("paused")
        break

    case MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing:
        print("playing")
        break
    }   
}

func moviePlayerPlaybackDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
{
    print("moviePlayerPlaybackDidChange")

    let state: MPMoviePlaybackState = (youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer.playbackState)!

    switch state
    {
        case MPMoviePlaybackState.Stopped:
        print("stopped")
        videoIDIndex = videoIDIndex + 1
        playNextVideo()
        break

        case MPMoviePlaybackState.Interrupted:
        print("interrupted")
        break

        case MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingForward:
        print("forward")
        break

        case MPMoviePlaybackState.SeekingBackward:
        print("backward")
        break

        case MPMoviePlaybackState.Paused:
        print("paused")
        break

        case MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing:
        print("playing")
        break
    }
}

func playNextVideo()
{
    if segueIdentifer == "SegueFromPlaylistVideos"
    {
        print("Playlist")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(
            self,
            name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
            object: youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer
        )

        print("videoIDs_ARRAY = \(videoIDs_ARRAY)")
        print("videoIDs_ARRAY[videoIDIndex] = \( (videoIDs_ARRAY[videoIDIndex] as String) )")

        youtubeVideoPlayer?.videoIdentifier = videoIDs_ARRAY[videoIDIndex] as String
    }
}
```

The sequence are as follows when the first video is played in the playlist, and I tap the forward to move to the next video:

> moviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChange
>
> moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange
>
> moviePlayerPlaybackDidChange
>
> playing
>
> playing
>
> moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange
>
> playing
>
> moviePlayerPlaybackDidChange
>
> stopped
>
> Playlist
>
> videoIDs_ARRAY = ["NztC0z1JNq0", "uqRBijuCZd8"]
>
> videoIDs_ARRAY[videoIDIndex] = uqRBijuCZd8
>
> moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange
>
> stopped

As you can see at the end, the state of the player is **stopped**.

I'm not sure how to resume it so it will play the next video. I've tried to add `youtubeVideoPlayer?.moviePlayer.play()` within `moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange` but the player does not resume playing.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I don't know syntax in Swift so please translate objective-c to swift 

I have 2 solutions for you problem :- 

    1. You can stop current playing video syntax in objective-c like 
    [self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer stop]; 
    and then you can set new video 

    self.youtubeVideoPlayer.videoIdentifier=videoIdentifier;
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
            [self.youtubeVideoPlayer presentInView:self.playerView];
            [self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;

     2. You can do like this 
    set nil to your XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController reference and set it again 

    self.youtubeVideoPlayer = nil;
    self.youtubeVideoPlayer = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleNone;
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

     and then you can set new video 

    self.youtubeVideoPlayer.videoIdentifier=videoIdentifier;
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
            [self.youtubeVideoPlayer presentInView:self.playerView];
            [self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;

Example: -
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *urlArray;
    int arrindex;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    urlArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"zVyEPNIR-yk",@"r5RXlY3at-E",@"sUFKakydp2c",@"1xvLHxFUwIk", nil];
    arrindex = 0;
    NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange1:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange1:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [self setVideo];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)setVideo
{
    self.videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

    [self.playerView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    NSString *videoIdentifier =[urlArray objectAtIndex:arrindex];
    self.videoPlayerViewController.videoIdentifier=videoIdentifier;

    self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
    [self.videoPlayerViewController presentInView:self.playerView];
    [self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=TRUE;
}
- (IBAction)Next:(id)sender {
        arrindex++;
    if (arrindex<urlArray.count) {
        self.videoPlayerViewController=nil;
        [self setVideo];
    }
}
- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange1:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = notification.object;
    MPMovieLoadState state = moviePlayerController.loadState;
    if (state & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)
    {
        [self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
    }
    else if (state & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
    {
    }
    else if (state & MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
    {
    }
}

- (void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange1:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    long reason=(long)self.videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.playbackState;
    if (reason==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"I'm Not Playing");
    }
    else if (reason==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"I'm Playingggggggggggggggg");
    }
    else if (reason ==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"pause....................................");
    }
    else if (reason ==3)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Interrupteddddddddddddddddd");
    }
    else if (reason ==4)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Seeking Forward");
    }
    else if (reason ==5)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Seeking Backward");
    }
}

@end

I hope this helps you.
```

Comment: It "temporarily" works...when I hit the forward button, it plays the next video, but its in the `MPMoviePlaybackState.Stopped` state when it plays the next video instead of being in the `MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing` state. Then when I tap the forward button again, it does nothing but the video stops.

Comment: Which Solution have you try 1 or 2 ?

Comment: I have implement save coding in my Project its working Correctly. May be you have made small mistake some where. so check it again or put your latest code here so may be i can help you.

Comment: can you possibly post your Obj-C code on github for me to look?...You don't have to post all code, just this part?...I'm like to run a test of it and convert to Swift. Right now, I tried both solutions, and the issue is as described in my previous statement.

Comment: I have edit my answer with Example.
Refer that.
I hope that code helps you.

Comment: haven't had a chance to test the code yet, I'll let you know.

Comment: using your exact code in Obj-C, it does work, but I'm still having issues with mine....one to note though `self.youtubeVideoPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleNone;` does not work when calling `presentInView`. The controls are hidden only if calling `addSubview`, and I'm using `self.view.addSubview(movie player.view)` because I'm using custom controls.

Comment: You have to change code in XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.m.
Replace below code in presentInView:(UIView *)view method
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

with 
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone

Then its working Fine.